# Run test in memory db play framework

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, automated-tests, specs2

I'm trying to run some tests for my application. 
It should be possible to run tests in a fresh new memory database but I won't get it to work.

My test looks like this now:

```
"Server" should {

"persist data for personal user properly" in {
  running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {

    //Create personal users
    val add1 = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/rest/personaluser").withFormUrlEncodedBody("name" -> "user1" , "email" -> "email@test1.com", "password" -> "test123", "gender" -> "male", "birthdate" -> "Oct 1, 2013", "nationality" -> "Sweden")).get
    val add2 = route(FakeRequest(POST, "/rest/personaluser").withFormUrlEncodedBody("name" -> "user2" , "email" -> "email@test2.com", "password" -> "test123", "gender" -> "male", "birthdate" -> "Oct 1, 2013","nationality" -> "Sweden")).get
    status(add1) must equalTo(OK)
    status(add2) must equalTo(OK)

    //Count users
    personalUserRepository.getAllPersonalUsers().length must beEqualTo(2)

    //Verify users exist
    personalUserRepository.checkIfPersonalUserExists("email@test1com") must beTrue
    personalUserRepository.checkIfPersonalUserExists("email@test2com") must beTrue

    //Verify user don't exist
    personalUserRepository.checkIfPersonalUserExists("email@test3com") must beFalse

    //Find user by email
    val findUser = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/rest/personaluserbyemail/email@test1.com")).get
    status(findUser) must equalTo(OK)
    contentAsString(findUser) must /("name" -> "user1")
    contentAsString(findUser) must /("email" -> "email@test1.com")
    contentAsString(findUser) must /("gender" -> "male")
    contentAsString(findUser) must /("nationality" -> "Sweden")
    contentAsString(findUser) must /("facebookID" -> "0")

  }
 }
}
```

When I run this I get the error `InconsistentDatabase: Database 'default' is in inconsistent state!`.
Is this because the standard inMemoryDB might not support MySQL that I've used for the default database?

However, I tried to add the memoryDB like this instead:

Defined it here

```
def memoryDB = Map("db.default.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:playdb;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=1")
```

And use it like this:

```
"Server" should {

"persist data for personal user properly" in {
  running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = memoryDB)) {
```

But when I do it like this, it don't use the in memory db, the test fails at `//Count users` because it is not equal to 2, but 7. It uses the real database anyway, not my new fresh memory db I try to use in this FakeApplication.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Any answer that could put me on the right track is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying I'm not well-acquainted with Play. You never mentioned how you configured the JDBC driver. I suspect that while in test mode, the application is still using the MySQL driver class against the H2 DB. You will need the H2 jar file in your test classpath too.